# What is the protocol that is used between web apps that share information?

Tags: security, web-applications, integration, account

- "Log in with Amazon" directs an e-shop to Amazon's interface where you can sign in and then authorize the other e-shop app. Now you can log in and use amazon account info on the e-shop.
- "Log in with Facebook" directs some arbitrary app to Facebook's interface where you can sign in and then authorize the other web app. Now you can log in and use facebook account info on this app.
- "Log in with Google" does the same thing for most web apps using Google account integration.

So what is this protocol called? Some web app has a page that authorizes apps somehow and it is important to note that it does this **securely**.

Comment: OAuth. http://oauth.net/2/

Comment: @Gray what do we call the visual login panel for Oauth? And what are the names of the panels for the intermediate stages of Oauth? ("Yes, I'd like to share" screen, Login screen, "confirm permissions" screen)

Comment: It's probably best for you to just read up on how it works. The link I gave previously describes the process, and here's google's explanation, which is particularly good: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2 . I doubt there are official terms for each part of the process that everyone uses, so it is best to just know what they do and describe them properly. This is another good source for that: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp

Comment: I know how oath works i asked a specific question. Don't undermine people.

Comment: Just trying to help. Sorry you didn't find it useful. Also, undermine doesn't mean what you think it means, lol.

Comment: you're doing it again

Comment: Well, I did my best to answer your original question. I'll admit I got sassy, but that's because you took my sincere answer as patronizing (I assume). Imagine if you tried to help a stranger and they responded how you did. In any case, there's not much else for me to say. If I were you, I'd read how the big guys like Google describe these things, and then use the same terminology. I don't think that is an unhelpful suggestion. You asked what the protocol was called, and I told you it was oauth. How could I assume you know how oauth works when I thought you didn't even know what it was called?